# How to print loss value which was set in keras backend function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to keras.
The below code snippet is for policy gradient loss function.
I tried to print the loss value to see if the loss value could be negative for policy gradient. but I couldn't.
Is there any way to print it?

I found some ways, but it uses keras history and seems like you can get history from model.fit function.
The below code does not use model.fit function.

```
from keras import backend as K

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

------------------------------------------------
action_prob = K.sum(action * self.model.output, axis=1)
cross_entropy = K.log(action_prob) * discounted_rewards
loss = -K.sum(cross_entropy)

optimizer = Adam(lr=self.learning_rate)
updates = optimizer.get_updates(self.model.trainable_weights,[],
                                loss)
train = K.function([self.model.input, action, discounted_rewards], [],updates=updates)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use for loop for train like epochs:

```
for epoch in epochs:
    train=K.function(..)
    K.print_tensor(loss, message='{} Epochs Training Loss = '.format(epoch))
```

Comment: I tried but i got an error like  `Print (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2018-08-20.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.print instead of tf.Print. Note that tf.print returns a no-output operator that directly prints the output. Outside of defuns or eager mode, this operator will not be executed unless it is directly specified in session.run or used as a control dependency for other operators. This is only a concern in graph mode. Below is an example of how to ensure tf.print executes in graph mode:` the code used keras, no tensorflow session.